# UnsatisfiedDependencyException for mapper class

Tags: spring, jhipster, mapper

I have created jhipster application. when I start the application I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryServiceImpl' defined in file [/server_2/target/classes/com/test/test/service/impl/CategoryServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.test.service.mapper.CategoryMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

can you help me please?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.test.service.mapper.CategoryMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: The exception is telling you that spring is not able in finding a bean of type `com.test.test.service.mapper.CategoryMapper`; this can happen for several reasons; for example spring is not scanning the right packages and so the `com.test.test.service.mapper.CategoryMapper` is not found and it's not possible to inject it.

Comment: Well the error is sort of clear. You have your `categoryServiceImpl` object which is being instantiated from `CategoryServiceImpl`, which takes a constructor parameter of type `CategoryMapper`, but you don't have one.

Comment: but my code was automatically generated by jhipster

Comment: entity, service, mapper and controller were generated by jhipster automatically by JDL through the command jhipster import-jdl ./src/model/Model.jdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoryMapperImpl` is generated at build time by mapstruct annotation processor from `CategoryMapper` interface that was generated by JHipster when importing your JDL file, make sure you have run `mvnw` or `gradlew` to generate it before starting your app.

See official doc about using  DTOs: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-dtos/